OTEL for Camel kafka batch processing with camel 4
We have an application where we are processing camel kafka messages through batch consumption and we are using camel 4 with java 17 , we are able to have open telemetry trace id for each poll
we are facing issue with duplicate traceid for multiple polls
and how can we have separate traceid for each message in single poll, if maxpollrecords is 3 and if we get 3 message can we have separate traceid to each message?
